# Problem with File uplolad in javascript

Tags: javascript, file, upload, appendchild

I have used javascript to upload more than one file. when user clicks on 'add more' javascript appends new object to older div using innerHTML. 
Now the problem is if I select a file and then click on "add more" then new file button exist but older selected file removes and two blank file buttons display. I want this old file must be selected when user add new file button.

Below is the code which I have used.

```
function addNew()
{
    var root = document.getElementById('newAds');
    newAd = document.createElement('input');
    newAd.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    newAd.setAttribute('name', 'uploaded[]');
    newAd.setAttribute('id', 'uploaded');
    newAd.setAttribute('value', '');
    newAd.setAttribute('maxlength', '1024');
    root.appendChild(newAd);
    root.innerHTML += '<br />';
}
```

If anybody can,
Help Plz!!!
tnX.

Comment: Can you provide some sample JavaScript & HTML. It's impossible to solve just by guessing at what the problem is.

Comment: How many fields do you end up with after you add a new field? What browser are you trying this in?

Answer (score 1):

Are you giving the new file fields new names? Are you overwriting any existing innerHTML or just appending?

**Edit**

One thought, maybe each time the function is run, the variable newAd gets reused so it recreates all the previous inputs.

I haven't done it this way in a while. I use jQuery so it's pretty simple then:

```
 $('#newAds').append('<input type="file" name="uploaded[]" id="uploaded" /><br />');
```

Another thought, you have the same id on all the inputs...this might cause a problem.

Comment: function addNew() 
{ 
var root = document.getElementById('newAds'); 
newAd = document.createElement('input'); 
newAd.setAttribute('type', 'file'); 
newAd.setAttribute('name', 'uploaded[]'); 
newAd.setAttribute('id', 'uploaded'); 
newAd.setAttribute('value', ''); 
newAd.setAttribute('maxlength', '1024'); 
root.appendChild(newAd); 
root.innerHTML += '<br />'; 
} 


I thinks it's overwriting each time when we add new item.

Comment: can you post that in your question...it's just a little hard to read here

Comment: I'd go with browser quirk on multiple file inputs with the same id.